# What is "Nor'n Iron" short for?

Tags: abbreviations

I was reading a post on a website when I ran into this title.

> How's about ye? is a very, very **Nor'n Iron** expression with which I am
>   sure The Great Panjandrum is regularly greeted by his kith and kin.

Source: [Wordreference](http://forum.wordreference.com/threads/greeting-hows-you.204356/)

I don't know what it means and that is okay, but I only want to know what *Nor'n* is short for in *Nor'n Iron*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"[Nor'n Iron](https://www.inyourpocket.com/belfast/How-till-spake-Norn-Iron-A-guide-to-local-phrases_70619f)" refers to Northern  Ireland  speech.

> - Contraction of Northern Ireland. Northern Ireland said in the Ulster dialect sounds like Norn Iron and therefore evolved into a Northern Irish saying.

Comment: Thanks for the clear answer, and the interestingly informative link, Absolute Beginner. Are you really Absolute Beginner? Maybe, but probably in post-advanced stuff, whatever that field is.